# How can I whitelist onedrive using the "quintolabs qlproxy" for web filtering

Tags: onedrive

I am useing quintolabs qlproxy for web filtering. How can I whitelist onedrive so it stays syncronized? What are the URLs and IPs to Whitelist?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is that OneDrive application uses SSL Pinning and thus does not accept mimicked SSL certificate from your Squid proxy. A similar issue for Dropbox is explained at http://docs.diladele.com/faq/squid/dropbox.html.

This same error will be present in all SSL inspecting web filters. For example from the message at Sophos (astaro) UTM support forum it seems the list of domain names to exclude is quite large (see https://www.astaro.org/gateway-products/network-protection-firewall-nat-qos-ips/56579-microsoft-onedrive.html):

```
    skyapi.live.net
    storage.live.com
    skydrive.live.com
    shared.live.com
    onedrive.live.com
```

Please note the list may not be complete. The best is to fire up the WireShark or (better) Microsoft Message Analyzer on the machine where OneDrive is installed and try to see what domain names are sent to the proxy upon start of OneDrive application. Then exclude these from ssl bump.